# visions and such of other religions-how does judaism view it?

Tags: nevua-prophecy

every religion has visions of characters in their religion.this is most common among christians with near death experiences with The Nazarene,but buddhists meet amitabha and padmasambhava and go to purelands,hindu gurus meet vishnu,kali and shiva and go to their respective realms etc

are these negative forces playing a ruse?how does Judaism explain mystical experiences of other religions?what do the mekubbalim say about it?

of course Judaism has these experiences aswell.but how can these other religions have these experiences?

all these religions have logical or scriptural errors so a vision doesn't prove them true,but why would Hashem allow forces to mislead people like this?to create confusion?

Answer (score 3):

**[Deuteronomy 13:1-6](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0513.htm)**

> If there arise in the midst of thee a prophet, or a dreamer of dreams--and he give thee a sign or a wonder,
>
> and the sign or the wonder come to pass, whereof he spoke unto thee--saying: 'Let us go after other gods, which thou hast not known, and let us serve them';
>
> thou shalt not hearken unto the words of that prophet, or unto that dreamer of dreams; **for the LORD your God putteth you to proof, to know whether ye do love the LORD your God with all your heart and with all your soul.**
>
> After the LORD your God shall ye walk, and Him shall ye fear, and His commandments shall ye keep, and unto His voice shall ye hearken, and Him shall ye serve, and unto Him shall ye cleave.
>
> And that prophet, or that dreamer of dreams, shall be put to death; because he hath spoken perversion against the LORD your God, who brought you out of the land of Egypt, and redeemed thee out of the house of bondage, to draw thee aside out of the way which the LORD thy God commanded thee to walk in. So shalt thou put away the evil from the midst of thee.
>
> (My emphasis)

Answer (score 0):

The non-Jews receive their effluence (שפע) from Hashem by way of the "seventy guardian angels" (שבעים שרים), one angel for each of the seventy nations. (This is a common trope in Kabbalistic literature - partly based on verses in this week's Parsha, בהנחל עליון גוים... כי חלק ה' עמו - and is mentioned, among many others, by Pnei Yehoshua to [Kiddushin 31a](https://www.sefaria.org/Penei_Yehoshua_on_Kiddushin.31a.2?vhe=Penei_Yehoshua,_Warsaw_1861&lang=he).)

That being the case, it should hardly be surprising that they might see visions of those spiritual forces or of their physical manifestations/avatars.